# How to get id from label?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a project and need the id of the label to store it and put it in a modal that will be displayed to the user. How to get the id in place of the name that is between the tags?

```
window.saveAndDisplay = function() {
var result = document.getElementById('demo');
var list = document.getElementById('dropBox');
while (list.children.length > 0) {
    result.appendChild(list.children[0]);
}
```

}

Comment: Link complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/qvynf0k9/

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem

```
window.saveAndDisplay = function() {
    var result = document.getElementById('demo');
    var list = document.getElementById('dropBox');
    var dragA = document.getElementById('dragA');
    var dragB = document.getElementById('dragB');
    var dragC = document.getElementById('dragC');
    result.textContent = "Names are: "
    if(dragA.parentNode == list){
        result.textContent +=  dragA.textContent+ " ";
    }
    if(dragB.parentNode == list){
     result.textContent +=  dragB.textContent + " ";
    }
     if(dragC.parentNode == list){
        result.textContent +=  dragC.textContent +  " ";
    }

}
```

This is not a good way to solve this problem. But it is the one that requires the least amount of explanation so will be more useful to you I hope. 
In general, you should put all those labels into a list so you can access them all through that list.

Comment: I do not understood.

Comment: Can you clarify precisely what you're trying to do? The wording is a little unclear. If you want to get the id of an HTML element that is the way. Is that not what you want?

Comment: OK sorry. The complete code is in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/qvynf0k9/, when I click on the "submit" button it shows the text between the "label" tag, but I need is the id of the tag

Comment: I have edited my answer, that should fix your problem if I've understood you correctly

Comment: It did not work, when I click the submit button it shows: Marko Maric, Ana Ladic and Ivan Saric, I need the id of the label: DragA, DragB, DragC

Comment: Apologies, I realized what you meant just as I replied, try replacing your function with the one in my answer, I've tested it

Comment: Ok, but if in the place of "label" I had a "li", would this work?

Comment: Would be exactly the same yeh

Comment: And a line break?

Comment: Line breaks shouldn't really be used but wont have any impact on the javascript side for the most part, can you mark my answer as correct if it helped you please

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you have HTML like :

```
<pre>
    <body>
      <ul id='dropBox'>
        <label name="message" id='theMessage'> Hello My World! </label>
      </ul>
      <ul id='demo'>
      </ul>
      <script src="scripts/so.js"></script>
    </body>
</pre>
```

therefore you tried to find label's id inside ul. I would expect ul->li->label neither ul->label, anyway let's look further.
If I get `label` as a child element of the list (`ul`), the console shows label#message which is a name of the label, then I changed to appeal to children by adding id property and got `theMessage`

```
result.appendChild(list.children[0].id);
```

Can you please post sample HTML? otherwise it a bit difficult to reproduce code and provide a fix.